# Option to migrate questions to stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Sometimes I stumble upon programming questions that are nor embedded-device specific, but instead ask about good practices, coding style or the programming language. An example:

[Use of global variables in Embedded Systems](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97241/use-of-global-variables-in-embedded-systems)

I think it would be interesting to add an option in the flag dialog to migrate to Stack Overflow, where there are more readers that could help the op faster with general programming questions.

Comment: It looks like this is is your first post on Meta.  Keep in mind that up- and down-votes have a different meaning.  On meta, up- and down-votes simply mean "agree" or "disagree" benignly.  (On the main board, down-vote means that the question is not well researched, unclear, not useful.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev Ok, I'm fine with either, tough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the last 90 days (from 3/4/2014), we have migrated 2 questions to StackOverflow. That is not enough to justify a dedicated migration path.

Answer (score 2):

The particular question you cited is actually a good example of what DOES belong here.  Global variable versus other ways to solve the same problem is one of the areas where being on a small resource-limited machine matters.

So to respond to your request, no, there is no need for a direct migration option to SO because:

You seem to have the wrong idea what should be migrated to SO, thereby your impression of how often it is necessary is skewed.

What W5VO said, which is that the volume of migration to SO is tiny.

Comment: I disagree. Programming in memory-constrained environments is not the exclusive domain of embedded devices. For instance, back in the day JavaME devices were quite constrained as well, and questions clearly belonged to SO (where there's a dedicated tag). I think there's also an "embedded" tag BTW.

Comment: @MisterSmith just because they fit there does not mean they also don't fit here, if they fit here and are asked here they should stay here.

Comment: @Kortuk I think you mean "just because they fit there does not mean they also DON'T fit here".

Comment: @Passerby Fixed whoops.